# C# Net Core System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm having the following error, I can't start this class, I would like you to help me solve it please.

Error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'IcarusOnlineAPI.Services.Email.SendEmail' while attempting to activate 'IcarusOnlineAPI.Controllers.Auth.AuthController'.
> at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
> at lambda_method10(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization.RequestLocalizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
> at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

```
    -Constructor Class--
    private readonly ICARUS_Login_DatabaseContext _loginContext;
    private readonly ICARUS_User_DatabaseContext _userContext;
    private readonly ICARUS_Char_DatabaseContext _charContext;
    private readonly WEBContext _webcontext;
    private readonly ILogger<AuthController> _logger;
    private readonly SendEmail _sendEmail;

    public AuthController(ILogger<AuthController> logger, 
        ICARUS_Login_DatabaseContext loginContext,
        ICARUS_User_DatabaseContext userContext, 
        ICARUS_Char_DatabaseContext charContext, 
        WEBContext webcontext,
        SendEmail sendEmail
        )
    {
        _loginContext = loginContext;
        _userContext = userContext;
        _charContext = charContext;
        _webcontext = webcontext;
        _logger = logger;
        _sendEmail = sendEmail;
    }

-- Send Email Class-


   using IcarusOnlineAPI.MailSender;
   using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
   using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
   using System.IO;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IcarusOnlineAPI.Services.Email
{
    public class SendEmail
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _env;
        private readonly AadGraphApiDelegatedClient _aadGraphApiDelegatedClient;
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

        public SendEmail(IWebHostEnvironment env,
            AadGraphApiDelegatedClient aadGraphApiDelegatedClient,
            IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _env = env;
            _aadGraphApiDelegatedClient = aadGraphApiDelegatedClient;
            _configuration = configuration;
        }

        public async Task SendRecoverAccountEmail(string Login, string Email, string Token)
        {
            await Task.Delay(10000);

            var emailTemplate = File.ReadAllText
                (Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "EmailTemplates/RecoverAccount.html"));

            var emailContent = emailTemplate
                .Replace("{Login}", Login)
                .Replace("{Link}", _configuration["Url"] + "/RecoverAccount/" + Token);

            var emailMessage = new EmailBuilder()
                .CreateHtmlEmail(Email, "Recuperar Conta", emailContent);

            await _aadGraphApiDelegatedClient.SendEmailAsync(emailMessage);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to register dependency for SendMail class

Answer (score 1):

The error is self-explanatory. you have `public AuthController(SendEmail sendEmail)` and Dependency Injection doesn't know how to instantiate `sendEmail`. It's not a good practice to pass concrete (class) variable in Controller's DI. You want to do something like this:

```
public interface ISendEmail { ... }
public class SendEmail : ISendEmail { ... }
```

and in `startup.cs` have something like

```
services.AddScoped<ISendEmail, SendEmail>();
```

Then in controller you would have

```
private ISendEmail _sendEmail;
public AuthController(ISendEmail sendEmail) {
   _sendEmail = sendEmail;
}
```